# Angular JS : 10 $digest() iterations reached. aborting watchers fired in the last 5 iterations when calling server funtion with in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

View:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 product-padding" ng-repeat="product in productList | filter:query | orderBy:'name'| offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage " ng-cloak>
                <div class="theme-04-scope">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <small class="defaultImageSize" ng-if="checkImageAttribute(product.ItemAttributes) == true">
                            <img class="ui-corner-all img-responsive defaultImageSize" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{loadProductImage(product.ItemAttributes)}}" />
                            @*ng-src="/Product/LoadProductImage/{{loadProductImage(product.ItemAttributes)}}?width=200&height=144"*@
                        </small>

                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Angular JS Controller:

```
    // Get product image. 
    $scope.loadProductImage = function (itemAttributes) {
        var imageId = 0;
        $.each(itemAttributes, function (index, data) {
            if (data.AttributeId == 1000700 && data.DataXml != null) {
                imageId = data.DataXml;
                return false;
            }
        });
        productRepository.getProductImage(imageId, 200, 144).then(function (imageArrary) {
            $scope.itemIdArr.push(imageId);
            $scope.productImage = imageArrary;
        });
```

Reporsitory:

```
getProductImage: function (imageId, width, height) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/Product/LoadProductListImage', JSON.stringify({ id: imageId, width: width, height: height })).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
        return $scope.productImage;
    }
```

Comment: Is productList or product getting modified somewhere while the ng-repeat is executed? Are your products identified by an ID for example? If so, add a track by statement to your ng-repeat... I assume when you load the Image, something in your productList is changed auf causes ng-repeat to reevaluate again sind again...

Comment: @MichaelRose, Product list is not modifying any where, it contains product image id, which I am passing through {{loadProductImage}} to load image from server. I have used track by but that did not work in my case. As I can understand, problem is coming due to deferred.promise. Thanks