# Call API function inside ng-repeat, prompting error. 10 $digest() iterations reached. aborting in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope function defined in my controller which is calling an API to fetch data from database. I am using this scope function inside ng-repeat. But when I run the application, it is getting hanged.

View:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 product-padding" ng-repeat="product in productList | filter:query | orderBy:'name'| offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage " ng-cloak>
                <div class="theme-04-scope">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <small class="defaultImageSize" ng-if="checkImageAttribute(product.ItemAttributes) == true">
                            <img class="ui-corner-all img-responsive defaultImageSize" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{loadProductImage(product.ItemAttributes)}}" />
                            @*ng-src="/Product/LoadProductImage/{{loadProductImage(product.ItemAttributes)}}?width=200&height=144"*@
                        </small>

                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Angularjs controller:

```
// Get product image. 
    $scope.loadProductImage = function (itemAttributes) {
        var imageId = 0;
        $.each(itemAttributes, function (index, data) {
            if (data.AttributeId == 1000700 && data.DataXml != null) {
                imageId = data.DataXml;
                return false;
            }
        });
        productRepository.getProductImage(imageId, 200, 144).then(function (imageArrary) {
            $scope.itemIdArr.push(imageId);
            $scope.productImage = imageArrary;
        });

        return $scope.productImage;
    }
```

Repository function:

```
 getProductImage: function (imageId, width, height) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/Product/LoadProductListImage', JSON.stringify({ id: imageId, width: width, height: height })).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216783/angular-js-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-watchers-fired-in-the-las)

Answer (score 1):

When you place a function inside of view interpolation, it gets evaluated at least twice every digest cycle, which can be many times per second. As such, it is not a good idea to put an API call into one of these functions.

```
.directive('getProductImage', function ($http) {
    return {
        scope: {
            imageId: '@imageId',
            width: '@width',
            height: '@height'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.info(scope.imageId, scope.width, scope.height)
            $http.post('/Product/LoadProductListImage', JSON.stringify({ id: scope.imageId, width: scope.width, height: scope.height })).success(function (data) {
                scope.imageArrr = data;
            });
        },
        template: '<img class="ui-corner-all img-responsive defaultImageSize" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{imageArrr}}"></img>'
    }
});
```

... which would appear in your view looking something like this:

```
<span get-product-image width="200" image-id="200" height="144"></span>
```

Enjoy..